# How to find all imported (in code) dependencies within a TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to bundle 3rd-party libraries into a vendor bundle using webpack, but doing so by scanning all TypeScript files in the tree and that way to identify the package imports, and return them in an array, instead of manually maintaining an array of the dependencies.

I found a package on npm that does just that, https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-imports - but unfortunately only for .js files and not TypeScript.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you might want to check out the [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) feature of webpack. It allows you to specify a directory and a regular expression to match the names of contained files against.

The following example imports all files matching `/\.ts$/` from `'path/to/folder'`. The second argument `true` indicates that the specified folder should be queried recursively (including sub-folders).

```
const myImports = require.context('path/to/folder', true, /\.ts$/);
myImports.keys().forEach(myImports);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try an [AST generator](https://dsherret.github.io/ts-simple-ast/)

```
// get them all
const imports = sourceFile.getImportDeclarations();
// or get the first one that matches a condition
const importWithDefaultImport = sourceFile.getImportDeclaration(i => i.getDefaultImport() != null);
const someModuleImport = sourceFile.getImportDeclaration("module-specifier-text");
```

The example is taken from this page: https://dsherret.github.io/ts-simple-ast/details/imports

Edit: `ts-simple-ast` has been renamed to `ts-morph`, please research further by yourself.