# How to allow specific values for an icon dynamic import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dynamic-import, zod

I have created a dynamic import to use icons from our library. It looks something like this:

```
// icons file
export { ArrowLeft } from './ArrowLeft';
export { ArrowRight } from './ArrowRight';
export { Checked } from './Checked';
export { CircleCar } from './CircleCar';
```

And this is the component:

```
import * as Icons from '../../components/Icons';
import * as z from 'zod';

const Schema = z.object({
  content: z.object({
   iconName: z.string()
   })
})

type JustAReactComponentProps = z.infer<typeof Schema>

const JustAReactComponent = ({content}: JustAReactComponentProps) => {
   const SecondaryIcon = Icons[content.iconName] as React.JSXElementConstructor<any>;//is this the correct type btw?
   return <SecondaryIcon />
}
```

And lets say that we have 30 icons and someone tries to set `iconName` as an icon that is not in the list, how can I enforce with Typescript that only the ones in the `icons` file are enabled to be used?

This question below seems to have the same problem I do but the solutions do not work for me(And I'm not looking for an external package).
[How to find all imported (in code) dependencies within a TypeScript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596983/how-to-find-all-imported-in-code-dependencies-within-a-typescript-project)

Comment: Do you mean `({ content }: JustAReactComponentProps) => {` instead of `({content: JustAReactComponentProps }) => {`?

Comment: thanks @alexanderbird